# Equation has different number of arguments

Tags: haskell, types

I made these data types to represent guitar tabs and I'm trying to write the `show` function to print them as real guitar tabs. `data`s are not my specialty and I'm having trouble matching up the types.

The error is

> Equations for `show' have different numbers of arguments
>       In the instance declaration for GHC.Show.Show Tabs.Chord'

The code:

```
type Strings = Int

data Fret = None | Note Int

instance Show Fret where
  show None = "-"
  show (Note a) = show a

data Chord = EmptyChord Strings | Chord [Fret]

instance Show Chord where
  show EmptyChord a = init $ take (a * 2) ['-', '\n' ..]
  show Chord (x : xs) = x : '\n' : show xs
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second instance needs more parentheses:

```
instance Show Chord where
  show (EmptyChord a) = init $ take (a * 2) ['-', '\n' ..]
  show (Chord (x : xs)) = x : '\n' : show xs
```

Comment: Seems to work. I'm having trouble fixing the expression. I might make another question for that